# How to add before_validation callback to single object, not whole class in ActiveRecord 3?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

How to add before_validation callback to single object, not whole class in ActiveRecord 3?
In AR 2 I did like this:

```
module ObjExtend  
    def before_validation  
        p 'before_validation'  
        return super  
    end  
end  
obj.extend ObjExtend
```

but it does not work anymore

Answer (score 1):

That's because in rails3 you can no longer just define methods in your models named for the callback in question. You have to declare them with `before_validation :foo` or what have you (:foo refers to an instance method of the model class but you can also pass in a proc or a class).

So.. This isn't the ideal solution but it should give you some ideas:

```
obj = MyModel.first
class << obj
  before_validation :foo
  def foo
    p 'before_validation'
    return super
  end
end
```

This code opens the object's 'eigenclass' (there's various names for this thing) and behaves as though it were the original class context.